# How to determine that a c source file is compiled into an .exe or .sys in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have a c header file and a c source file. The two files define several structures and functions used by both the user mode .exe file and the kernel mode .sys file. I would like to do something in the header file like this:

```
#ifdef _kernel_mode //included by a .sys project, 
//do something  
#else  //included by a .exe or .dll project
// do other things
#end
```

The macro _kernel_mode is fake. I would like to know the real name of the macro which functions like _kernel_mode in visual-c++. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If it's a header file with structures that can be used in both kernel and usermode, why do you need preprocessor definitions to detect if its being compiled for kernel or usermode? They should behave the same way shouldn't they? Anyways according to MSDN it should be `_KERNEL_MODE`

Comment: For example, there is a function named ParseMessage. Both user mode and kernel mode program can use this function to parse the message sent from another program. Since the message struct is the same accoss the two modes. Both the two mode programs can use the header file and also the source file.

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you mean? You want the implementation of the function to change depending on whether you're compiling for kernel or usermode but the function prototype remains the same?

Comment: It is related to a macro defined in <ntifs.h> in kernel mode and <winioctl.h> in user mode. However, it is the same. You are absolutely right.